# Scheduling algorithm in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, scheduling

does anybody now which scheduling algorithms are implemented in windows xp? Is there any possibility to install/use ULE algorithm? I think no.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot change (i.e. install) different scheduling algorithm of windows. It's implemented when it is designed. And i also read somewhere that Windows NT based OS' use a Multilevel Feedback Queue as the scheduling algo.

> a multilevel feedback queue is a scheduling algorithm. It is intended
>   to meet the following design requirements for multimode systems:
>
> 1. Give preference to short jobs.
> 2. Give preference to I/O bound processes.
> 3. Quickly establish the nature of a process and schedule the process accordingly.
>
> Multiple FIFO queues are used and the operation is as follows:
>
> 1. A new process is positioned at the end of the top-level FIFO queue.
> 2. At some stage the process reaches the head of the queue and is assigned the CPU.
> 3. If the process is completed it leaves the system.
> 4. If the process voluntarily relinquishes control it leaves the queuing network, and when the process becomes ready again it enters
>      the system on the same queue level.
> 5. If the process uses all the quantum time, it is pre-empted and positioned at the end of the next lower level queue.
> 6. This will continue until the process completes or it reaches the base level queue.
>
>    - At the base level queue the processes circulate in round robin fashion until they complete and leave the system.
>    - Optionally, if a process blocks for I/O, it is 'promoted' one level, and placed at the end of the next-highest queue.
>        This allows I/O bound processes to be favored by the scheduler and
>        allows processes to 'escape' the base level queue.
>
> In the multilevel feedback queue, a process is given just one chance
>   to complete at a given queue level before it is forced down to a lower
>   level queue.

Comment: That is not really a correct description of the Windows NT-family scheduler. In step 1, change "top-level FIFO queue" to "the queue for its current priority". For step 6, change "the base level queue" to "the queue for its base priority" (which is usually not the lowest level queue in the system). Also, promotions for I/O completion are of varying numbers of levels, depending on the I/O device; and, change "process" to "thread" throughout.  There is more; see the _Windows Internals_ book.

Comment: When I used XP, it had the behaviour of a round robin (with out multilevel feedback queue): a single cpu intensive task would stave the system. I think I read somewhere that they added multi level feedback queue with the SMP, and had two different kernel, depending on if you had multi-core or not. This would explain why Microsoft told us that we needed a duel core system, to do better multi-tasking (it was needed to get the basic performance that we were used to in Unix). I think this better scheduler is now enabled even for single core.

Comment: @richard No. It's been multilevel (32 priority levels) since NT 3.1.

Comment: So is the performance still terrible, when a process tries to hog the cpu (assuming one cpu-core, or one hog per core).